# Latex errors: undefined control sequence, outer par mode, underfull & overfull hbox

Tags: tables

I am attempting to put a Stata regression table in Latex, but my code yields the following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence \estwide{PEAssignment2tabl1.tex}{6}{c}
Not in outer par mode. \begin{table}[htbp]
Undefined control sequence \estwide{PEAssignment2tabl1.tex}{6}{c}
Undefined control sequence \estwide{PEAssignment2tabl1.tex}{6}{c}
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (240.51797pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Code begins:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}% Thanks to David Carlisle

\let\estinput=\input% define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
    \vspace{.75ex}{
        \begin{tabular*}
        {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
        \toprule
        \estinput{#1}
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace[.75ex]
        \end{tabular*}
        }
    }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
    \vspace{.75ex}{
        \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
        \toprule
        \estinput{#1}
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace[.75ex]
        \end{tabular}
        }
    }

% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
    \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

% *****************************************************************
% Custom subcaptions
% *****************************************************************
% Note/Source/Text after Tables
\newcommand{\figtext}[1]{
\vspace{-1.9ex}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,font=footnotesize}
\caption*{\hspace{6pt}\hangindent=1.5em #1}
}
\newcommand{\fignote}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}

% Add significance note with \starnote
\newcommand{\starnote}{\figtext{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01. Standard errors in parentheses.}}

% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables
\sisetup{
    detect-mode,
    tight-spacing       = true,
    group-digits        = false ,
    input-signs     = ,
    input-symbols       = ( ) [ ] - + *,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-post   = false
    }

\begin{document}
\title{Assignment 2 \\ \vspace{0.001 mm} {\large Program Evaluation, Spring 2014} \\             \vspace{0.001 mm} {\large Sarah Armstrong}}
\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Characteristics by the Amount of Co-Holding (\pounds)}
\estwide{PEAssignment2tabl1.tex}{6}{c}
\label{table2}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I found the preamble code at http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to turn your code into a *complete* and *self-contained* [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Are you sure all of the code that you say is in your preamble is actually in your preamble? You should *not* be getting the undefined control sequence error if it is. This is why a complete MWE that reproduces the error would really help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Please, let me know if I reformatted my code correctly for the question. I believe that I still have all of the code that was previously described as being included in my preamble  still in that location.

Comment: Do you really need `\vspace{0.001 mm}` ? If you can see a space that narrow your eyes are better than mine:-)

Comment: Your example still isn't a _MWE_ which would be something that people can use locally, you could edit the question to replace the input (or not quite so convenient) simply post another code block containing `PEAssignment2tabl1.tex`

Comment: No, the \vspace was a holder that I was going to go back and change! So that I understand, the example would be MWE if I attached the PEAssignment2tabl1.tex file with the question?

Answer (score 4):

The (first) error from tex from the code posted is not one of the ones you list it is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\estwide ...tracolsep \fill }l*{#2}{#3}} \toprule
```

`\toprule` is defined by the booktabs package which you have not loaded. If I add

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

and comment out

```
  %\estinput{#1}
```

as I don't have the file

Your example runs without error.

Comment: What do you mean by comment out \estinput{#1}?

Comment: After doing so, I now receive the error: Missing } inserted \estwide{PEAssignment2tabl1.tex}{6}{c} over and over again.

Comment: @SKA I meant I changed it as shown in my answer putting a `%` at the start of the line (otherwise I get an error the file does not exist) presumably you would not get that error.

Comment: @SKA If you add booktabs as in my answer and do not include any file you get no error. If you get an error after inputting `PEAssignment2tabl1.tex` then the assumption would be the error is in that file, which you have chosen not to show. At this point my crystal ball is unfortunately rather cloudy.